# NSString Memory Warning in objective c

Tags: objective-c

```
NSString* strSubject = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: temp  encoding:   
NSISO2022JPStringEncoding];
```

i got a memory message "Potential leak of an object allocated" on above line.
Is there any alternate way to write same.

Comment: Where do you release strSubject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get that sort of message unless you either release it or put it in the autorelease pool.

This can be done by:

```
NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: blah blah blah ... ];
[str release];
```

to do it immediately. You can also use:

```
NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: blah blah blah ... ];
[str autorelease];
```

to have it released at some point in the future.

Comment: paxdiablo means you need to do `[strSubject release]` or `[strSubject autorelease]` :-)

Comment: Thanks, @smalduck, I incorporated that into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `[strSubject release]` later, or `[strSubject autorelease]` either later or immediately. I'd use this:

```
NSString* strSubject = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:temp encoding:NSISO2022JPStringEncoding] autorelease];
```

Sadly there isn't a NSString factory method `stringWithData:`, but that's equivalent.

In fact any `[NSString stringWithBlah:xx]` method is more or less equivalent to `[[[NSString alloc] initWithBlah:xx] autorelease]`